# Webcomic about "small differences" ruining a date (specifically one of them likes YOHpt1 the other YOHpt2)

Tags: story-identification, star-trek, star-trek-voyager, webcomics

Trying to track down a webcomic. The panels are a back and forth between a couple on a first date. Something like
"What do you do mostly?"
"oh watch a lot of tv?"
"whats your fav show?"
"star trek"
"omg which series?"
"voyager"
"omg which season?"
"five"
"omg which episode?"
etc etc

They get more and more excited, Eventually they narrow it down to year of hell part 1 and part 2 and this difference in preference is enough to end the date.

Comment: Sounds like a take on Emo Philips' joke about religion

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because mentioning a SF show in a webcomic doesn't make it a SF webcomic.

Comment: @DJClayworth where should I ask the question?

Comment: @TheIronKnuckle please don’t repost comments and keep pinging people. That said I believe this should be fine to be asked on [literature.se], though be sure to check their help centre first.